# Is sum query in Realm android, synchronous(blocking) OR async?

Tags: android, realm

In Realm I know there are async as well as sync queries, that's why I wanted to know Is sum query sync or async? I have read their documentation but didn't find anything.

Comment: @Pavel with sum operator there is no need to write findall or findallasync

Comment: So, can you call sum() on UI thread?

Comment: @PrimožKralj I am currently calling from UI thread, but I don't know is it async/sync ?.

Comment: I am wondering that too. Because if you have millions of rows, it can make a big difference if this is async or not.